# How can I search for NON-saved questions?

Tags: support, search, saves

By using `in:saves`, it is possible to search among only questions saved by the user, However, using `-in:saves` does not appear to restrict the search to questions which the user has *not* saved.

Is there some way to achieve this?

For example, a user may want to read through all questions under some small tag, and then keep track of those that have already been read by marking them as 'saved', so that searching later only returns questions the user hasn't been exposed to yet.

If there is a way of achieving this *without* having to search for 'non-saved questions', this would be equally useful. Essentially any method which would allow the user to 'mark as read' questions (like you would in an email inbox) and then (perhaps the more important bit) to filter out these marked questions from the search.

Comment: @RobertLongson in theory one can save thousands on posts, and on smaller sites, there aren't that many posts to begin with, so in those cases it does have merit to have such feature.

Comment: Also, it can be helpful when I don't wanna see search results which includes questions which I already saved.

Comment: @RobertLongson Presumably it would be used in conjunction with other filters.

Comment: The "edit" label was removed for a reason. Anyway, you can just say "Any workaround is welcome" which is both shorter and less confusing than what is currently written.

Comment: I would have thought `in:.saves` would work but it doesn't.