# Allow us to use the [-] symbol to exclude results in other operators, not just tags

Tags: feature-request, status-review, search

I can use `-` before a tag to mean "not that tag". For example, [I can search for "not python" on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bpython%5D). However, this doesn't seem to work for other operators. For example, using `-user:me` [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Thunno+2%22+is%3Aa+-user%3A114446) still comes up with a bunch of my own answers.

The interesting thing here is that it recognises what you want it to do, as it says `not containing user:114446` under "Search Results". But, it doesn't actually do it.

So, is it possible for `-` to be extended to other search operators (e.g., `user`)?

Comment: Quite related to a similar question I asked earlier today: [How can I search for NON-saved questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390669/how-can-i-search-for-non-saved-questions)

Comment: @Paradisi it's a wider request. Doing this will also have side effect of doing what you asked for, but since it's more complex to implement and not very likely to be done, not really a duplicate.

Comment: "*The interesting thing here is that it recognises what you want it to do, as it says not containing user:114446 under "Search Results". But, it doesn't actually do it.*" I doubt it recognizes what you expected. `-string` keyword will exclude results with the *word* `string`. So `-user:me`, although the auto-fill ID works, will exclude results with the *word* `user:<your user id>` instead.